# Angular JS on BigCommerce Checkout

Tags: angularjs, checkout, bigcommerce

I am working on the checkout part of a BigCommerce Website. I did notice that has an "angular.module" on the script and I am thinking that that triggers every change on the form and on the Cart Review. Is there any documentation on that on how change or insert some of the codes?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Hi! could you please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hello @IgnacioCatalina I want to determine if I can change values on the code with a determinant for example if the Payment Method I want to set some changes on the total price. This can't be add by the normal BigCommerce Admin Dashboard.

Comment: You can't do that in the checkout. And even if you managed to hack something together to accomplish that, you risk that a change in the checkout code will break your code and prevent shoppers from completing their checkout.

Comment: Even using API? @IgnacioCatalina

Comment: You want to change the total price of a cart using the APIs?

Comment: You will have to have a managed checkout that you host somewhere. There was no possible way that we could find in order to manipulate the price even removing the taxes for exempt selections during the BC checkout flow, so we went to the route of creating a hosted checkout based on Themevale's one page checkout plugin by utilizing the CartAPI.